# How to automate startup of a web app with several independent processes?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, rake

I run the [wesabe](https://github.com/wesabe/mesabe) web app locally.
Each time I start it by opening separate shells to start the mysql server, java backend and rails frontend.

My question is, how could you automate this with a shell script or rake task?

I tried just listing the commands sequentially in a shell script (see below) but the later commands never run because each app server creates its own process that never 'returns' (until you quit the server).

I've looked into sub-shells and parallel rake tasks, but that's where I got stuck.

```
echo 'starting mysql'
mysqld_safe
echo 'starting pfc'
cd ~/wesabe/pfc
rails server -p 3001
echo 'starting brcm'
cd ~/wesabe/brcm-accounts-api
script/server
echo 'ok, go!'
open http://localhost:3001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the output being messed, put a "&" at the end of the line where you start the application to make it run in background.

Comment: Thanks, that kind of works. The problem now is that the browser launches before the server(s) finish booting. Is there a way to make some kind of callback, maybe by grepping the output for the success message?

Comment: You can make the scrip wait a couple seconds before next command with a line like "sleep 15" between them (15 seconds).

Comment: It's pretty common to start the processes in the background with `&`, then either sleep as @Paulo said, or just open the browser like you're doing. The browser opening before the server is ready shouldn't hurt anything though it might give you some visual noise about the connection not being made. A browser refresh should clear that up nicely. If you have to have a clean browser load, you could easily write a little app to loop over some gets from the target URL until you get a clean response, then exit so the script could continue and launch the browser.